# How to get files/photos sorted?

Tags: onedrive

I cannot find in the documentation how to get the content of a folder/album sorted by "creationDate, lastModified, size, ....".

I m interested to know what changed since the last time my application connected to OneDrive and I was expecting to use the LastModified sorting.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do any research on the topic before posting this question? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/onedrive/organize-photos-files-faq -> This might help.

Comment: I did.Ok, you probably missed the tags and I was not very clear then. It s using the OneDrive REST API

Comment: You're right, I did miss that. Part of my comment still stands though, what have you tried?

Comment: So I m currently using the API and I can get albums, photos and documents. When I try to use the call with recent_docs I get an empty response. Please see there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680723.aspx#recent_docs. Also if I can make it work I cannot control the sorting. Hence my question

Answer (score 0):

The new OneDrive API, which is described at http://onedrive.github.io/odata/optional-query-parameters.htm,  supports sync tokens and sorting.   You can find more detailed documentation about at http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm and http://onedrive.github.io/odata/optional-query-parameters.htm respectively.

Comment: the view changes is exactly what I wanted. Thanks !